# Adding new options causes issues

Tags: powershell, remote-access

I have been able to create and frankenstein a menu to help me as IT support and am still learning powershell to read and write it proficiently but am confused why if I put more options I run into issues mainly at the end.

```
Function Menu 
{
Clear-Host        
Do
{
    Clear-Host                                                                       
    Write-Host -Object 'Please choose an option'
    Write-Host -Object '**********************'
    Write-Host -Object 'Scripts to run' -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Write-Host -Object '**********************'
    Write-Host -Object '1.  Ping PC '
    Write-Host -Object ''
    Write-Host -Object '2.  Restart ELP Desktops '
    Write-Host -Object ''
    Write-Host -Object '3.  Restart NOVI Desktops '
    Write-Host -Object ''
    Write-Host -Object '4.  Check PC Storage '
    Write-Host -Object ''
    Write-Host -Object '5. Check all user adpw exp'
    Write-Host -Object ''
    Write-Host -Object 'Q.  Quit'
    Write-Host -Object $errout
    $Menu = Read-Host -Prompt '(0-5 or Q to Quit)'
 
    switch ($Menu) 
    {
        1 
        {
            $Computer = Read-Host Please Enter Host name
        Get-WMIObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Computername $Computer | `
        Where-Object {$_.IPEnabled -match "True"} | `
        Select-Object -property DNSHostName,ServiceName,@{N="DNSServerSearchOrder";
            E={"$($_.DNSServerSearchOrder)"}},
            @{N='IPAddress';E={$_.IPAddress}},
            @{N='DefaultIPGateway';E={$_.DefaultIPGateway}} | FT 

            pause
        }
        2 
        {
        restart-computer -ComputerName ##### -force
        }
        3 
        {
        restart-computer -ComputerName ####-force
        }
    4
    {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName (Read-Host -Prompt "Please Enter Host name") {Get-PSDrive | Where {$_.Free -gt 0}}
pause

        }
            
        5
        {
        get-aduser -filter * -properties passwordlastset, passwordneverexpires |ft Name, passwordlastset, Passwordneverexpires 
        pause
            }
       
             

        Q 
        {
            Exit
        }   
        default
        {
            $errout = 'Invalid option please try again........Try 0-5 or Q only'
        }
  
        }
        }
        until ($Menu -eq 'q')
        }   
 
# Launch The Menu
Menu
```

Comment: I was going to edit this and try to clean up your question but when I did I get many errors testing your code.
If you remove the ```clear``` does your work ? 
Your ```pause``` should probably be ```start-sleep -seconds 5```

Comment: what are those issues?

Comment: There is no issue right now except IF i add more options I have issue with the closing brackets event if I add open and a close before   }
        }
        until ($Menu -eq 'q')
        }   
 
# Launch The Menu
Menu